# JPanel goes partially out of JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code:

```
class ScrolledPane extends JPanel
{
    JScrollPane vertical;

    public ScrolledPane(JComponent list)
    {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(200, 200);
        vertical = new JScrollPane(list);
        vertical.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy
            (JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(vertical);
    }
}
```

If I add it into a JFrame and add Components to the list, I end up with the contents going out of the JFrame instead of it using the Scrollbar.

how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: add: `setLayout(new BorderLayout());`

Comment: This way the JScrollPane fills the ScrolledPane JPanel

Comment: You're forgetting that JPanel uses FlowLayout by default, and components can overflow a FlowLayout-using JPanel, and other layouts would be better suited to prevent this, as recommended above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks, works